# Serde untagged enum — bail prematurely when variant matches “shape” of incoming data but fails validation

Tags: rust, serde

I am using serde to deserialize an untagged enum. Naturally, untagged picks the first variant which can be successfully deserialized from the incoming data. After trying every variant, if no variant could be successfully deserialized, it returns `data did not match any variant of untagged enum MyEnum`.

I would like to do something similar but different: I would like a way to signal that a variant matches the “shape” of the incoming data, and so it is the right variant for serde to try to deserialize into, but that the variant fails *validation* for another reason. So deserialization into the variant is unsuccessful, but deserialization into other variants should not proceed. My goal here is for serde to print a better error message indicating the reason deserializing into the matching variant failed (i.e., which conditions were violated when validating), although I suppose improved performance by not doing needless work would also be a plus.

[Example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=454b73d22c84c8d4ae69e215c334824a):

```rust
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer}; // 1.0.160
use serde_json; // 1.0.96
use std::error::Error;

fn de_nonempty_vec<'de, D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Vec<i32>, D::Error>
where
    D: Deserializer<'de>,
{
    let v = Vec::deserialize(deserializer)?;
    if v.is_empty() {
        return Err(<D::Error as serde::de::Error>::invalid_length(
            0,
            &"must be nonempty",
        ));
    }
    Ok(v)
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct A {
    #[serde(deserialize_with = "de_nonempty_vec")]
    a: Vec<i32>,
}
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
#[serde(untagged)]
enum MyEnum {
    A(A),
}
fn main() {
    let good_json = r#"{ "a": [1] }"#;
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<MyEnum>(good_json));
    let bad_json = r#"{ "a": [] }"#;
    println!("{:?}", serde_json::from_str::<MyEnum>(bad_json));
}
```

As expected, we get

```
Ok(A(A { a: [1] }))
Err(Error("data did not match any variant of untagged enum MyEnum", line: 0, column: 0))
```

But the shape of the incoming data, `{ "a": [] }`, does match the enum I'm trying to deserialize into. `MyEnum::A` is the right variant to pick, and validation should fail because, once picked, the `A` cannot be deserialized because it needs a nonempty Vec. I'd like the error to message to be more or less the same as if I'd tried to deserialize `A` directly:

```
Err(Error("invalid length 0, expected must be nonempty", line: 1, column: 11))
```

Maybe something like `error when deserializing into MyEnum::A: invalid length 0, expected must be nonempty`. Is this something serde is capable of without implementing `Deserialize` from scratch?

Comment: What about first deserializing, then validating?

Comment: Do you mean deserialize into the `MyEnum` and then validate its variants? I'd like to be able to use an `A` outside of a `MyEnum` knowing it passed validation. If I rely no validating a `MyEnum`, then I can only safely use an `A` if it's stored in a `MyEnum`.

Comment: Oh, I think I realize what you meant. I'd prefer the error to happen during deserialization if possible.

Comment: I think what @ChayimFriedman suggests is defining twice your types, one for deserializing and one for validation. You first deserialize, then convert the data into the other type while validating it. Then, the final data has a type that ensures all the invariants that you want to be held. This can be automated with macros. Note that the conversion step can occur during in the implementation of `Deserialize` of the second type.

Comment: @jthulhu There is no need to create a separate type if validation does not change the type.

Comment: Part of the issue is that I'd like to use the `A` both when it's part of a `MyEnum` and as a standalone object (both constructed by deserializing). In the latter case it makes sense to error during deserialization, but that breaks the `untagged` behavior I want. This might be possible by adding `UnvalidatedA` and `UnvalidatedMyEnum::A(UnvalidatedA)`, then implementing some `TryFrom`s, but that seems like quite a bit of boilerplate.

Comment: @ChayimFriedman that depends on what underlying types are used. If the type is defined in the crate, then it is possible to create it while violating its invariants, but it might not be possible otherwise. For instance, if I used an external crate to have a type of integers different of one, it might not be possible *at all* to instantiate a value of that type if it's a one, despite that (probably) being a validation error and not a deserialization error. Plus, it might be easier to maintain code that does not rely on violating some invariants at one point, then validating them later.